# Is there an API equivalent of the Facebook Access Token linter/debugger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

Is there a graph API equivalent of the [Facebook Access Token linter/debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) that I can call programmatically?

The linter is nice.  It tells you all sorts of cool information about the token you have, such as the permissions granted (available to me via `me/permissions`), the issue and  expiration dates, the App ID, App name, profile Id, User Id, User Name, if it is valid (available to me if I try to call `/me` and watch for the exception returned), and the origin.

```
App ID:      APP ID : APP NAME
Profile ID:  PAGE NAME
User ID:     ID : NAME
Issued:      1328916821 : 3:33 pm Feb 10 2012
Expires:     1334100821 : 4:33 pm Apr 10 2012
Valid:       True
Origin:      Web
```

So how about it?  Is there a programmatic way to get this info without having to resort to screenscraping the linter tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now possible with the `debug_token` endpoint

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-debug/

Comment: This has changed. The new endpoint is `debug_token`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/debug_token

Answer (score 4):

It's possible. Now you can check what information is associated with the access token you have.
Simply Fire this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={input-token}&access_token={access-token}
input_token: the access token you want to get information about
access_token: your app access token or a valid user access token from a developer of the app
```

Source https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't exist I'm afraid. What were you wanting it for ooi??

Comment: I think it would make a great question.  Many people (most of them new) on s/o ask access_token questions, then this is sometimes a follow up question to their other questions.  And I figured it was worth it's own question all to itself.

Comment: But what would you use the API for? I can't think of any compelling reasons to have API access for this info. If there's a good reason it may get built :)

Comment: I found the answer below and have changed it to the correct answer.  The facebook API is always changing and it's hard to stay on top of everything.  The API would be used to find out what perms the user accepted for the app, so I can limit the app's functionality and not call into the API for things that user did not grant.

Comment: You can find out perms by GETing /me/permissions for a valid access token. You might want to know if the token has expired, I guess. It might also be useful for building something obscure like the Graph Explorer I suppose. Either way, it's built now. So yes, good catch and nice one on taking the time to update the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

You can get a JSON response from the URL debugger by adding &format=json to the URL, but this doesn't work currently for the access_token debugger.

Could file a bug for it!

Comment: do u mean like this.https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=xxx&format=json