# Facebook: How to get app id from user's access token - using /app?access_token=TOKEN?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

We're allowing a user to access our backend (using a REST api over https with json replies) using only a facebook access token as a credential, so we want to do two things:

1. verify the access token and find the user's id - which is just a call to https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=TOKEN
2. Make sure that this access token belongs to our facebook app.
   You can call 
   https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=TOKEN, but this seems to be an undocumented feature (and one which is sometimes rather slow).

Can anybody tell me whether this is in fact a standard method which is likely to stay there? Or is there another way of doing what we want to do: to verify that a user's access token is valid and comes from our facebook app.

You can call me/permissions and me?fields=installed, but neither of these seem to tell me WHICH facebook app we're checking.

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236445/is-there-an-api-equivalent-of-the-facebook-access-token-linter-debugger) on so. I don't think you really need to validate whether the access token belongs to your specific app. You just use it with your app and if it does not belong to it you get an error.

Comment: @Lego, thanks. But the thing is I am NOT getting an error - our backend just calls FB Graph API with the access token, and as long as it's valid, we can get the /me resource - it could be an access token from some other facebook app, right?

Comment: What I do not understand is why you should care about whether the access token belongs to you app, as long as you get the user data out of the token. Maybe I just do not see the whole picture.

Comment: So that nobody else can set up a facebook app, get people to add it, get their access tokens, and use them to talk to our backend on behalf of the user. I'm not sure why they'd want to do this, but still, it's a possible abuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass signed_request insted of access_token with every request.
Parameter signed_request based on secret key of your application and you can simple verify it. Read [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) about signed request.

Comment: If you use `FB.login` out of the JS SDK, the response you get _does_ contain a `signed_request` property. Post that to your server, validate it there … maximum level of security imaginable at this point reached IMHO.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea to me. I'll need to check that mobile app developers can get the signed_request too, but I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: But isn't signed_request used for the opposite? i.e verifying that info from Facebook are legitimate?

Answer (score 4):

You should implement an authentication flow as described in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (client or server side). Basically you get a fresh access token by authenticating the user with your app and use that token for requests to your server. This way you can be sure that the token "belongs" to your app. Steps to do:

1. Initialize a Facebook SDK of your choice with your app ID.
2. Check whether the user has already authorized your app.
3. If the user has already authorized your app you get his or her Facebook user id together with the token (which "belongs" to your app), if not: authenticate the user and get the token.

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) provide you with sample code and lots of details:

- For client side authentication look especially at [Status & Sessions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)
- For server side authentication have a look at [4. Exchange
  the code for a User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)

**UPDATE:**

The feature you mentioned is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) (scroll down to *2. Make requests to the API*):

> An app access token allows you to make requests as an application, not
>   a user. To retrieve the details of your application, perform an HTTP
>   GET on: 
>   https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN

Hence the feature is likely to stay.

Comment: Right... our problem is that we planned to dig out an access token in the front end/mobile app and just pass that to the backend, letting the backend verify the access token with facebook. But a valid access token does not in itself mean that the call to our backend is coming from a trusted party.

Comment: How do you define a trusted party? If you have a valid access token, then you have a valid user, even if the user has not authenticated with or authorized your app.

Comment: That's exactly my point. If you set up a "free beer coupons" facebook app and secretly use your user's access tokens to do stuff in our backend, you're not what I'd call a trusted party... But our own web frontend or mobile apps or whatever are "trusted" to just that. That's why I thought it would be neat to check (in the backend) which facebook app was used to get the access token.

Comment: So how do you get your friend's access token? Try that! That'll be pretty hard if you do not know login and password of your friend. Ok, you might ask him...

Comment: Hacker Henry can get innocent Irving's access token by setting up a facebook app that looks like a game or something. Irving signs up for that app, and suddenly Henry has Irving's access token. Henry can then use that access token to log in to our backend, pretending to be Irving.

Comment: Ok, you got me. Sry for the stupid questions. I've done a little more research and have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing though - the page you link to calls /app with an APP access token, I'm wondering whether doing this with a USER's access token is a documented feature. It works, but I can't see it mentioned in the docs... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but I've recently just had the same worries. I think the most straight forward way to do this is checking the access token with `debug_token`.

```
GET graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
 input_token={token-to-inspect}
 &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#checktoken